# Can we add a spoiler marker into topic précis?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, spoilers

We've seen

> that when inserting spoilers

only partial sentences

> remain visible in the title précis

which can be confusing.

---

Could we change that so the presence of a spoiler is seen in the précis?
That would make the above into, for instance…

> We've seen [sp] only partial sentences [sp] which can be confusing

Thoughts?

Comment: [Related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354158/259608) regarding handling of La-Tex in titles.

Comment: I don't have a link handy, but there's a related request around here somewhere asking for the same feature for images and code in posts.